# Restarting mysql after changing the data directory

Tags: mysql, mysqld-safe

I tried changing the data directory of mysql following these instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04). But now I can't get mysql to restart. The last step in the linked article is

```
    $ sudo systemctl start mysql
```

But I get the following error

```
    Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
    See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The info in journalctl -xe is as follows :

```
    Sep 10 16:03:06 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Sep 10 16:03:06 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
    -- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- 
    -- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
    -- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
    Sep 10 16:03:06 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- 
    -- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
    Sep 10 16:03:06 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Sep 10 16:03:06 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Sep 10 16:03:06 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    -- 
    -- Unit mysql.service has failed.
    -- 
    -- The result is RESULT.
```

Comment: Post output of `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: I don't have that file on my system.

Comment: OK; then wherever your MSQL error log is on your Distro